# Asteroids libGDX cosine and sine rotation equations, shooting bullets at wrong angle

Tags: java, libgdx, trigonometry

I've made a Asteroids game for a Android device, but had trouble noticing that the player was standing in a direction but firing the bullet in another slightly displaced direction. I've looked through the code and it only happens when the player accelerates and rotates. Not when the player is only rotating. I hope this code is enough to tell you something about it to give me a suggestion.

The player is rotating in the correct direction while the bullet isn't. I tried putting the update functions in different orders but that didn't help either. I do not see what the problem is because when shooting the player class creates a bullet every time with the radians from the player. So I think it has something to do with that the radians aren't updated when the bullet is fired.

```
private void initForces() {
    maxSpeed = 300;
    acceleration = 200;
    friction = 10;
}

private void initRotationSpeed() {
    // Radians are used to determine the angle the player points in
    radians = MathUtils.PI / 2;

    rotationSpeed = 3;
}

public void shoot() {
    final int MAX_BULLETS = 4;
    if (bullets.size() == MAX_BULLETS || isHit()) return;
    bullets.add(new Bullet(x, y, radians));
}

   public void update(float dt) {
        if (updateCheckIfPlayerHit(dt)) {
            return;
        }

        updateCheckExtraLives();

        // Forces
        updateAcceleration(dt);
        updateRotationSpeed(dt);
        updateTurning(dt);
        updateFriction(dt);

        // Set shape
        setShape();

        // Screen wrap
        wrap();
    }

   private void updateTurning(float dt) {
        // Turning: Tilt the screen to left or right to rotate the ship
        final float ROTATION_SENSITIVITY = 3;
        if (left || Gdx.input.getAccelerometerX() > ROTATION_SENSITIVITY) {
            radians += rotationSpeed * dt;
        }
        else if (right || Gdx.input.getAccelerometerX() < -ROTATION_SENSITIVITY) {
            radians -= rotationSpeed * dt;
        }
    }

    private void updateRotationSpeed(float dt) {
        x += dx * dt;
        y += dy * dt;
    }

    private void updateAcceleration(float dt) {
        // Accelerating
        if (up || Gdx.input.isTouched() && Gdx.input.getX() > 0 && Gdx.input.getX() < Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 2) {
            dx += MathUtils.cos(radians) * acceleration * dt;
            dy += MathUtils.sin(radians) * acceleration * dt;
        }
    }

    private void updateFriction(float dt) {
        // Friction
        float vector = (float)Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
        if (vector > 0) {
            dx -= (dx / vector) * friction * dt;
            dy -= (dy / vector) * friction * dt;
        }

        if (vector > maxSpeed) {
            dx = (dx / vector) * maxSpeed;
            dy = (dy / vector) * maxSpeed;
        }
    }
```

Bullet.java

```
package com.mygdx.entities;

import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.ShapeRenderer;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.MathUtils;

public class Bullet extends SpaceObject {

    private float lifeTime;
    private float lifeTimer;

    private boolean remove;

    Bullet(float x, float y, float radians) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.radians = radians;

        float speed = 350;
        dx = MathUtils.cos(radians) * speed;
        dy = MathUtils.sin(radians) * speed;

        width = height = 2;

        lifeTimer = 0;
        lifeTime = 1;
    }

    public boolean shouldRemove() {
        return remove;
    }

    public void update(float dt) {

        updateRotationSpeed(dt);
        wrap();

        updateLifeTime(dt);
    }

    private void updateRotationSpeed(float dt) {
        x += dx * dt;
        y += dy * dt;
    }

    private void updateLifeTime(float dt) {
        // How long time the bullet is supposed to live
        lifeTimer += dt;
        if (lifeTimer > lifeTime) {
            remove = true;
        }
    }

    public void draw(ShapeRenderer shapeRenderer) {
        shapeRenderer.setColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
        shapeRenderer.begin(ShapeRenderer.ShapeType.Line);
        shapeRenderer.circle(x - width / 2, y - height / 2, width / 2);
        shapeRenderer.end();
    }

}
```

And to shoot with the player the code is:

```
    if (Gdx.input.justTouched() &&
                    Gdx.input.getX() > Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 2 &&
                    Gdx.input.getX() < Gdx.graphics.getWidth()) {
        player.shoot();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to my question is that I forgot a bit of math. So in the Bullet constructor I don't have the player's speed in x- or y-direction so I made two static variables in the Player class and set them equal to the Player's dx and dy in the update rotation speed function. Both of these variables are floats.

```
private void updateRotationSpeed(float dt) {
    x += dx * dt;
    y += dy * dt;

    dxStatic = dx;
    dyStatic = dy;
}

public static float getPlayerDeltaX() {
    return dxStatic;
}

public static float getPlayerDeltaY() {
    return dyStatic;
}
```

In the constructor of the Bullet class I needed to add this:

```
Bullet(float x, float y, float radians) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.radians = radians;

    float speed = 350;
    dx = speed * MathUtils.cos(radians) + Player.getPlayerDeltaX();
    dy = speed * MathUtils.sin(radians) + Player.getPlayerDeltaY();

    width = height = 2;

    lifeTimer = 0;
    lifeTime = 1;
}
```

So this was what was causing the bullets to move in a slightly different direction.

EDIT: 
Or you could just add some float variables to the Bullet constructor and take in the player's dx and dy since a bullet is being created every time inside the player class. In my case it is at least. That might be a better alternative.

```
Bullet(float x, float y, float playerDeltaX, float playerDeltaY, float radians) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.radians = radians;

    float speed = 350;
    dx = speed * MathUtils.cos(radians) + playerDeltaX;
    dy = speed * MathUtils.sin(radians) + playerDeltaY;

    width = height = 2;

    lifeTimer = 0;
    lifeTime = 1;

}
```

Comment: Does every player move at the same velocity (i.e. in both the same direction and with the same magnitude)? I suspect not. This means that the variables should not be static. Instead, you should implement appropriate setters and getters for these values.

Comment: There is only one player, but I have changed so that the Bullet constructor take in the player's dx and dy (speeds). Isn't that almost the same thing as implementing setters and getters? (This is shown in the edit part of my answer)

Comment: My main point is that this is an improper use of `static`. It is **not** intended for sharing data to instances of other classes. Instead it is intended to be used when all instances of a class have the same value for a variable.

Comment: Oh, okay. Thanks for making me better aware of how to code :)